# Beamer moves up page number when using pgfputat

Tags: number, shift

I want to make a list on the left and add logos on the left.
pgfutat allows me to place the logos where I want, however when using it, it induces a top shift of the page numbering.

How to hinders this shift ?

Here is an example of the code I would like to use:

```
   \documentclass[t,compress,squeeze,smaller]{beamer}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                           
   \usepackage[english]{babel}
   \usepackage{pdfpages}
   \usepackage{pgf}

   \usetheme[shadow]{Berlin}
   \setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
   \usenavigationsymbolstemplate{}
   
   \addtobeamertemplate{footline}{\begin{flushright}
   {\normalsize \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber \hspace{1em}\null \vskip0pt}      \end{flushright}}

   \begin{document}

   \begin{frame}
   \begin{itemize}
   \item A
   \item B
   \item C
   \item D
   \end{itemize}
   \pgfputat{\pgfxy(8.5,1)}{\pgfbox[left,bottom]{\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{example-   image-a}}}
   \pgfputat{\pgfxy(8.5,-1)}{\pgfbox[left,bottom]{\includegraphics[scale=0.18]{example-   image-a}}}
   \end{frame}

   \begin{frame}
   \begin{itemize}
   \item A
   \item B
   \item C
   \item D
   \end{itemize}
   \end{frame}
   
   \end{document}
```